# Correct SQL Multiply across tables

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I am at the end of my rope. I am learning SQL for a class. I have tried to get something akin to the to work, but to no avail. Can someone take a look at it.

Keep in mind that I'm new to this. I am trying to get the code to make subtotal equal the sum of column **qty** multiplied by the sum of column **donutPrice** in the donut table. I can't find much except for joins and if I do that, I can't use the join as a value.

The ultimate goal is to make it kinda automated.

```
CREATE TABLE donut
(
  donutID int(50) not null auto_increment primary key,
  donutName varchar(50) not null,
  donutDesc varchar(200),
  donutPrice dec(8,2)
);
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customerID int(50) not null auto_increment primary key,
  fname char(50) not null,
  lname char(50) not null,
  address varchar(50) not null,
  apartment varchar(10),
  city char(50) not null,
  state char(2) not null,
  zip dec(5) not null,
  homeph varchar(10),
  mobileph varchar(10),
  otherph varchar(10)
);
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
  orderID int(50) not null auto_increment primary key,
  notes varchar(50) not null,
  orderdate date not null,
  customerID int(50) not null default 1,
  foreign key (customerID) references customer(customerID)
);
CREATE TABLE invoice_line_item
(
  donutID int(50) not null,
  orderID int(50) not null,
  qty dec not null,
  subtotal dec(10,2),
  subtotal= sum('qty'*'donutPrice') FROM (invoice_line_item, donut),
  primary key (donutID, orderID),
  foreign key(donutID) references donut(donutID),
  foreign key(orderID) references invoice(orderID)
);

ALTER TABLE donut AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
ALTER TABLE invoice AUTO_INCREMENT=500;
```

Comment: I think you're asking how to write a SQL query to use these tables to produce a subtotal. Can you please [edit] your question to show what you expect the  result of the query to look like?  By the  way, this line `subtotal= sum('qty'*'donutPrice') FROM (invoice_line_item, donut),` should not be in a table definition. It looks like it's intended to be  part of a query.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing here. I just want the value of subtotal to be a decimal value that consists of the multiplied sums of the table values. Should I do that through a view or a query?

Comment: You may be looking for https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html but generally speaking you should not store columns which can be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a result looking like this:

```
OrderID  subtotal
  1       12.50
  2       15.00
          27.50
```

You get that with a query like this:

```
 SELECT invoice.orderID, SUM(invoice_line_item.qty * donut.donutPrice) subtotal
   FROM invoice
   JOIN invoice_line_item ON invoice.orderID = invoice_line_item.orderID
   JOIN donut ON invoice_line_item.donutID = donut.donutID
  GROUP BY invoice.orderID WITH ROLLUP
```

Did you cover entity-relationship data in your class?  Your entities are invoice, invoice_line_item, and donut (and your other tables).  The relationships between them appear in the  `ON` clauses of the `JOIN` operations.

Start with a query, and get it working.  Then you can create a view ... which is nothing more or less than an encapsulated query.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want. I was just trying to do it as part of the field's properties. I guess you can't do that...

Comment: Right. You Can't Do That(TM). Some flavors of MySQL have computed columns in tables, but they can't refer to other tables.